# Boost 1.58 code not building for 32 bit

Tags: gcc, boost

I am trying to build boost 1.58.0 code for 32-bit. Using  below commands

```
./bootstrap.sh
```

I have noticed: It sets toolset as

**Building Boost.Build engine with toolset gcc... tools/build/src/engine/bin.linuxx86_64/b2**

After that I ran,

```
./bjam install --toolset=gcc address-model=32 variant=release,debug link=static,shared -d2 -q -j4 --layout=versioned --prefix=$OUTPUT_PATH_BUILD  --without-python --without-mpi --without-wave --without-graph --without-math --without-test define=BOOST_LOG_USE_CHAR >> $LOG_FILE
```

Above command builds the code for 64-bit, but I am expecting it for 32-bit.
Here is the out put in my LOG_FILE

```
[----------- start building boost
Thu Jan 28 23:17:06 PST 2016
Performing configuration checks

    - 32-bit                   : no  (cached)
    - 64-bit                   : yes (cached)
    - arm                      : no  (cached)
    - mips1                    : no  (cached)
    - power                    : no  (cached)
    - sparc                    : no  (cached)
    - x86                      : yes (cached)
    - lockfree boost::atomic_flag : yes (cached)
```

How to build the code for 32 bit? I am using ubuntu 14.04 and GCC 4.8.

Thanks.

Comment: According to [this](http://lists.boost.org/Archives/boost/2015/04/221334.php) the "bitness" shown in the configuration check is the default for the toolset, not the one you are using in this particular try. So you are (at least in theory) building for 32-bit.